# Error 0x887A0001 from SharpDX ResizeBuffers on Resize event

Tags: c#, resize, direct2d, sharpdx

I tried to make [this sample](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct2D1/MiniRect/Program.cs) resizable.

I added only this event handler on Resize, but I get error 0x887A0001. What can I do?

```
static void form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backBuffer.Dispose();
    renderView.Dispose();
    device.Dispose();
    swapChain.ResizeBuffers(1, form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, Format.Unknown, SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch);
}
```

Comment: I added some relevant tags and rewrote the title to mention the error number and more of the context. Then I inlined a link and fixed up the question text to flow a little more smoothly. Finally, I [removed a tag from the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: 0x887A0001 = DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL = "The application provided invalid parameter data".  Disposing the back buffer and then using Format.Unknown to use the existing buffer format isn't very healthy.

Comment: @HansPassant using Format.Unknown is totally allowed in that use case, it will keep the current format. Disposing the back buffer is also required before to call resize.

Comment: @NathanTuggy : remove the device.Dispose() call, you should keep your device alive. Also make sure that render view is not bound to the pipeline (set render targets to null before to dispose render view)

Comment: @NathanTuggy sorry directed message to wrong person, answered anyway ;)

Answer (score 4):

Since you do not release `backBuffer` and all associated resources, you'll have the following error in debug mode:

> DXGI ERROR: IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers: Swapchain cannot be resized unless all outstanding buffer references have been released. [ MISCELLANEOUS ERROR #19: ]

To make sure that everything is released and recreated properly, you can attach the following code between `stopwatch.Start()` (Line 88) and `RenderLoop.Run(...)` (Line 91):

```
form.ResizeEnd += (sender, args) =>
{
    device.ImmediateContext.ClearState();
    d2dRenderTarget.Dispose();
    backBuffer.Dispose();
    renderView.Dispose();
    surface.Dispose();
    swapChain.ResizeBuffers(1, 0, 0, Format.Unknown, SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch);
    backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);
    renderView = new RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);
    surface = backBuffer.QueryInterface<Surface>();
    d2dRenderTarget = new RenderTarget(d2dFactory, surface, new RenderTargetProperties(new PixelFormat(Format.Unknown, AlphaMode.Premultiplied)));
};
```

`device.ImmediateContext.ClearState()` is optional (in your case, using Direct2D, it's not needed, but generally it's a good idea to add it to also make sure that render target is not bound to the context anymore, since CLR will only dispose it on the need command buffer flush.